# Fewest permutation matrices to make every variable free

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have an under-determined homogenous linear system $Ax=0$ where matrix $A$ has dimensions $[m \times n], m<n$ and $rank(A) < m$. For example:

$A=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|[cccc]}
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4\\
\hline
r_1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
r_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
r_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$

*n.b.* Since I am not so familiar with MathJax, I have the row labels, $r_i$, and column labels, $c_i$, inside the matrix. The free variables of this matrix are $c_2$ and $c_4$.

If we permute the columns of the matrix and subsequently transform to reduced row echelon form (RREF), we see:

$A\cdot T=A'=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|[cccc]}
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_4 & c_3\\
\hline
r_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
r_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
r_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
\xrightarrow{\text{RREF}}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|[cccc]}
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_4 & c_3\\
\hline
r_1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
r_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
r_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$

The free variables are now $c_2$ and $c_3$ (note columns labels of the matrices).

**My question:** I would like to find the fewest possible permutation matrices $T$, such that the set of all free variables of the permuted matrices $A'$ contains all variables (=columns of $A$). If there is no analytical way of doing this, is there maybe a smart iterative way of finding or combining permutation matrices?

In this instance, two permutation matrices suffice. The identity matrix $I$ gives free variables $\{ c_2, c_4\}$. Matrix:

$T =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc]}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right] 
\xrightarrow{\text{}}
A \cdot T \overset{RREF}{=}
\left[
\begin{array}{c|[cccc]}
  & c_2 & c_1 & c_4 & c_3\\
\hline
r_1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & -1\\
r_2 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
r_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}
\right]
$

gives free variables $\{ c_1, c_3\}$. Thus the union of the free variables for permutation matrices $I,T$ is $\{c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4\}$, which is all the possible variables.

To give a sense of my actual problem: $A^{[59 \times 79]}$ and  $rank(A)=38$. I thus want the smallest amount of permutation matrices that gets all 79 variables to be free.

Comment: Note: it is not necessarily possible to make all columns into free columns. For example, with the matrix
$$
A=
\left[
\begin{array}{c|[cccc]}
  & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 & c_4\\
\hline
r_1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
r_2 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
r_3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
there is no way of permuting the columns of $A$ so that $c_1$ is a free variable.